# Cannot convert value of type int to specified value CGPoint

Tags: swift, xcode, cgpoint

I have some code that is supposed to swipe a sprite in any direction taking in an initial value of a CGPoint.

I tried setting up a variable for this as

```
    var initialLocation:CGPoint = 0
```

I know this is not how you're supposed to do it but I forgot how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a point, so it has to have two coordinates (x, y):

```
var initialLocation: CGPoint = .zero
```

or

```
var initialLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```